# How to show special french characters in a tooltip

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that shows a tooltip whenever mouse hovers over a picturebox. I have localized tooltip strings for different languages and it works fine for all languages except French.

For french language, it fails to show characters like `é, è, â, ô, à`, etc.
I'm sure that the strings are properly localized. But i fail to understand why this is happening?

For example, in code below, character `ô` is converted into a junk character.

```
ToolTip controllerToolTip = new ToolTip();
controllerToolTip.ShowAlways = true;
controllerToolTip.SetToolTip(controllerPictureBox, "Mappages du
contrôleur ou du clavier pour ce jeu");
```

Comment: *"I'm sure that the strings are properly localized."* They are probably not. Or at least not properly stored. Or not properly handled. .NET strings are Unicode all the way through. Show us the code!

Comment: What @atornblad is alluding to is that you've embedded the accented characters in your source file. Depending on the encoding used for that file (Latin1? UTF-8?), the characters might display differently in your text editor vs. when used. Consider using Unicode literals: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669.aspx

Comment: There are *no special characters*. .NET is 100% Unicode. You would only get into trouble if the text was stored using the wrong codepage instead of Unicode, or if you used a font that doesn't even support Latin 1

Comment: try to add cultureInfo , "Mappages du contrôleur ou du clavier pour ce jeu".ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("fr-FR"))

Comment: @Thorarins your code won't do anything at all since the input is already a string. There's nothing to format using a culture. Worse,  .NET uses *Unicode*. Forcing a specific codepage is actually the *cause* of the problem.

Comment: @niks_4143 what OS version are you using? What is the system's UI language? What font are you using to display the tooltip? If you are using a non-Unicode font like MS Sans Serif on a localized version of Windows, the font won't have the proper glyphs to display Windows-1252 characters

Comment: @pangagits the windows he is using might not be french from the start wich could be the problem